# Handle multiple REST service requests via a single HTTP request (batch REST service request)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm in need to support batch request in my RESTful services, in which the user sends a single request (http request) but that request issues multiple REST requests. However I don't know if there is any best practice for this.

Server-technology: Spring Web MVC.

Comment: "sends multiple REST requests in a single request" doesn't make any sense

Comment: @NimChimpsky: sometimes this "term" is used to describe a technique where one request is used to submit several commands at once (so the "mutlipe REST requests" are not http requests, think of them more like 2 commands, packed in one composite json object) -- Think of it like putting to fine grande commands into one big request. Something like this was some years ago often used in JEE communication to save bandwidth.

Comment: @Ralph, yes, you're right, and that's exactly what I need, to batch multiple chunks of requests in a single one to reduce the round trip time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an rest resource that represent your command queue.
Every command that gets added to this queue gets executed by the server.

Then add an PUT handler for this queue that accept a single command an put it in this queue.
This PUT handler could for example accept someting like this

```
{
  "commandType" : "x"
  "parameter" : {...}
}
```

then enhance the PUT handler so that is also accept a list of this commands:

```
{ "batch" :
 [
   {
      "commandType" : "x"
      "parameter" : {...}
   }
   {
      "commandType" : "y"
      "parameter" : {...}
   }
 ]
}
```

This is not very nice, but it should work.

Comment: I got your idea, thanks for that
to sum-up, adding a service like 
processQueue(@RequestParam CommandsQueue commands)
and CommandsQueue is something like your last json style, right?

Comment: But how can I scatter and gather requests/response respectively through different Controllers?

Comment: @TopCoder: you could do this with a lot of reflection, but I recommend to use the Command-Pattern and directly invoke the service layer.

Comment: is there any spring piece-of-code to dispatch the corresponding controller for each request? Imagine that I've requested 2 services /orders/1/details and /customer/1, so I need to dispatch a get request internally from the batch-controller to 'Orders-Controller' and another one to 'Customer-Controller'

Comment: @TopCoder: You have to write it by your own.